# Forgotten Icloud urername and password.

Tags: iphone

I changed my passcoad and I choosed off passcoad and then close my iph.

Comment: Sorry to hear about your iph's passcoad

Comment: It's important to know your urername

Comment: @owlswipe lol true. I was going to try to correct the question but I'm honestly not sure what OP is trying to say...

Answer (score 3):

Go to [iforgot.apple.com](https://iforgot.apple.com/) and follow the instructions.